# Is it possible to import/add eclipse code formatter .xml in SonarQube?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

The code below is a sample of what eclipse code format I want to use.

```
<profiles version="11">
    <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="equationStyle" version="11">
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.insert_new_line_before_root_tags" value="insert"/> 
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_annotation" value="insert"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
        .
        .
        .
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.never_indent_block_comments_on_first_column" value="false"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_then_statement_on_same_line" value="false"/>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Is it possible to import/add this to SonarQube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.This request partially relates to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-112

Comment: Hello! Are you sure? Thank you!